# Data Studio Case Statement - How to return original value?

Tags: looker-studio

I'm trying to make a calculated field. This is the Case statement I write.

```
case Rank
  when 0 then '-'
end
```

This works as expected but returns null for other values:

[image]

I want to show original value for values other than 0 (in this case, should be 1 instead of null). I tried this:

```
case Rank
  when 0 then '-'
  else Rank
end
```

but got this error:

```
Invalid formula - THEN/ELSE arguments have incompatible types: TEXT/ NUMBER. All THEN/ELSE arguments must return the same type.
```

[image]

I couldn't find any example. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Error in the second [CASE](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020724) statement is displayed because the **Semantic Type** (referred to as **Type** from here on) of the `Rank` field is **Number** whilst the `THEN` portion on line 2 (the dash `-`) is a **Text Type**:

> Invalid formula - THEN/ELSE arguments have incompatible types: TEXT/
> NUMBER. All THEN/ELSE arguments must return the same type.

The solutions below involve ensuring that all output is of a single **Type**, (in this case **Text**); there are a couple of approaches (use **EITHER** #1 or #2 below):

### 1) Change Type of `Rank` to Text in a Calculated Field

One approach is to incorporate the [`CAST`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7280720) function to change the Field **Type** to **Text**; the entire process can be done in a single [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) using the [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7067058) function:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(CAST(Rank AS TEXT ), "^(0)$", "-" )
```

### 2) Change Type of `Rank` to Text at the Data Source

The second way is to change the Field **Type** of `Rank` at the Data Source and use the second [CASE](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020724) statement with a small edit (wrapping 0 in quotes, thus `0` becomes `"0"`):

```
CASE Rank
  WHEN "0" THEN '-'
  ELSE Rank
END
```

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/189da52f-0188-4c05-9817-4a6ba00a3927) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]